Stronger than Lipschitz continuity on metric space
Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space (which can be compact and/or connected if needed).
Is there a natural function class (of $M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$-functions) that is strictly included in the Lipschitz continuous functions on $(M, d)$?
On the real line, the polynomials are among the most basic continuous functions, but those are not necessarily available in metric spaces.

To be clear, are you thinking about functions from $M$ to $\mathbb R$?

Polynomials are not Lipschitz on the real line (if the degree is 2 or greater).

Yes, functions from $M$ to the reals.  I did not claim polynomials are Lipschitz: just that they are rather basic (from a logical pov).

Do you mean something like the Hölder spaces $C^{k,\alpha}(M)$ for $\alpha\in [0,1]$ and $k\in\mathbb N$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition

How about the constant functions?

You may want to check out the paper by Nowik and myself on differential geometry via infinitesimal displacements.  There we have classes $D^i$ which are weaker than $C^i$ that might provide a strengthening of the Lipschitz condition.

Yes, we can consider the short maps. These are the morphisms in the category of Lawvere metric spaces, and they are given by the Lipschitz functions of Lipschitz norm $\le 1$, or equivalently functions satisfying
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le d(x, y), x, y \in M.$$
There are always a plentiful selection of these since the distance functions $d(x, -)$ for fixed $x \in M$ are always examples, and they form a convex subspace of the Lipschitz functions.
I suppose this is an extremely mild example of a strict containment, since every Lipschitz function can be rescaled to a short map.
